# How to SetFocus in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, setfocus

I have a Silverlight app with a user control that has several text boxes. I am using the MVVM pattern.

When I click the Add button, the ViewModel performs some logic. After the Add Command logic is complete, I want to SetFocus to the txtName textbox after each click.

How can I do this with a Silverlight UserControl and MVVM?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is no "IsFocused" property, but there are at least two MVVM-friendly approaches you could use:

1. Use the trigger/action set of extensions in the Blend SDK.  Specifically, use an [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger(v=expression.40).aspx) on your button's "Click" event, and then use a [`CallMethodAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.callmethodaction(v=expression.40).aspx) to call "SetFocus" on the target element.
2. Use a `Behavior` along with an attached property to call "Focus" on the target.

---

For the first, you would just need something like this:

```
<Button Content="Add"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=NameOfElementToFocus}"
                                 MethodName="Focus" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<TextBox x:Name="NameOfElementToFocus" />
```

(Alternatively, instead of using `CallMethodAction`, you could also use a simple ["focus"](http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2010/05/silverlight-focus-action/) action.)

---

I won't post any code for the second approach -- it is a common enough use case that you will be able to find examples by searching ([for example](http://jklogic.blogspot.com/2012/02/silverlight-setting-focus-to-text-box.html)).  The basic idea is to create a `Behavior` class, and add a boolean attached property "IsFocused" -- in its "change" handler, you then call "Focus" on the AttachedObject.  Then you can bind the property MVVM-style to a property in your view-model, something like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameOfElementToFocus" my:FocusBehavior.IsFocused="{Binding IsTextBoxFocused}" />
```

Comment: Oh McGarnagle, one day I must buy you a beer sir, I never thought of that simple callmethodaction route, cheers.